# How to add data to one session in laravel from multi steps form

Tags: laravel, session

i am trying to create multi step form using laravel and i followed ([add products](https://www.5balloons.info/multi-page-step-form-in-laravel-with-validation/)) steps. but still i cant put second step data into same session. i searched on internet but didnt get solution for that. can anyone help for that? i am new to laravel

```
        public function createStep1(Request $request)
{
    $product = $request->session()->get('product');
    return view('products.create-step1',compact('product', $product));
}

public function postCreateStep1(Request $request)
{

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',

    ]);

    if(empty($request->session()->get('product'))){
        $product = new Product();
        $product->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('product', $product);
    }else{
        $product = $request->session()->get('product');
        $product->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('product', $product);
    }

    return redirect('/products/create-step2');

}
    public function createStep2(Request $request)
{
    $product = $request->session()->get('product');
    return view('products.create-step2',compact('product', $product));
}


public function postCreateStep2(Request $request)
{
    $product = $request->session()->get('product');
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'address' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
    ]);

        $product = $request->session()->get('product');
        $product->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('product', $product);
```

/**
     * this step data didnt put into this session. i need to know how put these
     */

}
        return redirect('/products/create-step3');

```
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

At the beginning:

```
use Session;
```

To put something in session:

```
Session::put('product', $product);
```

To get it back:

```
Session::get('product');
```

Don't forget to forget it, when you're done:

```
Session::forget('product');
```

To flush everything:

```
Session::flush();
```

Comment: first step works correctly. but second step data didnt get from that session

Comment: You may want to assign it to a variable. `$product = Session::get('product');`
Also if you're getting it in a different file, make sure you're including Session - `use Session;` :)